# Calculate the number of clients (new and returning) for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, sum

everyone,

I am trying to form a query that shows the number of clients for a specific year. The clients table contains a field, client_since, all the clients info, active_client, date_deleted (that's used as a flag when clients unsubscribe to communications).

Every record's client_since shows the year they became clients (char(4)).
I get the record of the new clients when I query by year, however, I am trying to form the query to show me the number of clients (new and returning). For argument's sake, all clients are returning.

Say that I had 1 client in 2008, 6 clients signed up in 2009, another 6 clients signed up in 2010, another 10 clients signed up in 2011, and so on. I need the query to sum all the clients by year.

I got as far as:

```
select count (id) as [New Clients],client_since
from tax_clients 
where client_since >= 2008
group by client_since
```

and the result is:

```
new clients
1   2009
8   2010
6   2011
6   2012
11  2013
6   2014
9   2015
17  2016
20  2017
13  2018
26  2019
41  2020
7   2021
```

So, the calculation would adding all the new clients.

Can anyone give me some direction as to how to structure the query?

Thanks

Comment: Please define "new" and "returning"?  What if a client skips a few years?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: New client is a first-timer using the service and returning is a client that returns every year. If a client skips a year, it would be inactivated and when it returns, it would be considered a new client.

Comment: Why are you using unsupported software?

Comment: That's what I have. I don't do a lot of db stuff, just basic. One day I'll upgrade but today, that's what I am working with..

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to form the query to show me the number of clients (new and returning). For argument's sake, all clients are returning.

The "returning clients" logic looks a window sum:

```
select 
    client_since, 
    count(*) as new_clients, 
    sum(count(*)) over(order by client_since) returning_clients
from tax_clients 
where client_since >= 2008
group by client_since
order by client_since
```

Maybe very old versions of SQL Server would prefer a subquery rather than mixing aggregation and window functions in the same scope:

```
select t.*, 
    sum(new_clients) over(order by client_since) returning_clients
from (
    select client_since, count(*) as new_clients
    from tax_clients 
    where client_since >= 2008
    group by client_since
) t
order by client_since
```

Comment: Thanks. I get Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: I didn't mention that it is a sql 2008...replacing the over(order by...) with over(partition by...) gives the same result as the original query

2009 1 1
2010 8 8
2011 6 6
2012 6 6
2013 11 11
2014 6 6
2015 9 9
2016 17 17
2017 20 20
2018 13 13
2019 26 26
2020 41 41
2021 7 7

Comment: @Antonio: you need `order by`. `partition by` does not do the same thing. I updated my answer with an alternative that might work better on an old version such as youers.

Comment: lag() is not a recognized built-in function and I am still getting the syntax error on the last query Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: GMB, this query still gives a syntax error near order on line 2
select t.*, 
    sum(new_clients) over(order by client_since) returning_clients
from (
    select client_since, count(*) as new_clients
    from tax_clients t
    where client_since >= 2008
    group by client_since
) 
order by client_since

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have one record per year when the client is active, then you can use `lag()`:

```
select client_since, count(*) as num_active_clients,
       sum(case when prev_cs = client_since - 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_new_clients
from (select t.*,
             lag(client_since) over (partition by id order by client_since) as prev_cs
      from tax_clients t
     ) t
group by client_since
```

Comment: Hi, Gordon. Lag() is not valid for sql 2008...not a valid built-in function.